# React: render inline svg icon

Tags: svg, reactjs

I have this code for inline svg icon:

```
@Icon = React.createClass
  render: ->
    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <title>img</title>
      <g stroke-width="2" stroke="#0070D9" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M2 1h16a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v16a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1z"/>
        <path d="M1.652 14.514l4.956-6.279 5.448 5.579 6.398-5.579M13 3.95a2.05 2.05 0 1 1 0 4.1 2.05 2.05 0 0 1 0-4.1z"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

But react skip all properties with `-`, like: `stroke-width="2"`

Comment: Try to look at the console. React usually warns of incompatible attributes and suggests an action (removing, renaming). In your case, it is a camelCase issue as Lazarev has pointed out. You can also remove the `xmlns` which is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `camelCase`. For example: `strokeWidth` instead of `stroke-width`. I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9e47k0jn/1/) with working example.